# Problem with weight painting a mesh to bones

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, weight-painting

I'm having difficulties with creating toes on a humanoid 3D model. I have created toe bones that I would like to use in order to articulate the feet. I have the entire body mesh correctly weight painted to the rest of the bones, but in accommodating the new toe bones, these problems have arisen.

The toe bones are children of my feet bones. I have given the feet bones the vertices of half of the feet by subtracting away vertices I want to keep for the toe bone as shown below:

[image]

How do I go about adding vertices to the tow bones?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Select (or create) a vertex group of/for the toe, then paint the toe vertices with Add.